# How to deploy a website when I used NPM for JS dependencies?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I'm developing a website using `Angular2` and `TypeScript`. I followed the 'Getting started' from the official website, which is great. But at the end of the day, I found out that my node_modules has ~70MB of stuff.
What I don't understand is: is that all stuff really needed? When I'm testing my webapp, my browser doesn't download all of this, in fact, I don't think I download more than 2MB.

I'd like to embed the frontend part in a Spring Boot application for the backend part, but at this rate, I'm afraid the jar will be gigabytes-heavy...

I guess I missed something to be ready to release the frontend part, but as I mentioned, I didn't find it by myself.
How are you doing to deliver light websites when using `npm` and `node_modules`?

**Edit after suggestions about Webpack**

I'm understanding that Webpack is an alternative to System.js, that simplifies the dependencies management and helps the browser to download the proper libs and not everything, according to the runtime dependencies.
But it doesn't tell me if I should upload all these megabytes in node_modules on the server. (Or am I misunderstanding it?).
If I have to upload a version of my website on a server, how can I figure out which libs I should upload and which ones are not useful?

Comment: Are you using Webpack or System.js?

Comment: Try this - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#production-configuration

Comment: @Harangue I'm using System.js, just like the official tutorials told me to! As you and Sanket pointed out, it seems I should give a try to Webpack, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Sanket, thanks, I'll check it soon!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in switching to Webpack, a typical webpack config will generate a couple of `bundles` (js files). These JS files are all you need to distribute (along with your HTML files and static assets). You can be guaranteed that those bundles have everything you need in them, and you won't have to upload `node_modules`.

Comment: Ok, so I really misunderstood it: I didn't think it produces a bundle! This is very interesting, I'll look at it very soon!